# Getting ndk error: *** target pattern contains no `%'. Stop

Tags: android-ndk, contains

I moved a ndk project from windows to linux(ubuntu). Then suddenly i got above error. But this project build seamlessly in windows. Even I get this error while ndk-clean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The culprit was 'obj' temporary directory under jni. I just removed the 'obj' directory and everything is fine. Maybe Linux can't tolerate Windows temporary object files:) (Or confused with those files..)

Comment: Maybe the problem was with wrong upper/lowercase file and directory name transformations?

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit? Or any links. Just curious to know the differences ..

Comment: See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/399708/how-can-i-force-windows-to-make-a-file-lower-case-only

Comment: In my case the Android project moved from Windows to Mac. I removed the build folder created during the build on Windows and things started building smoothly.